# How do I fix this giant gap in my toolbar?

Tags: 10.04, gnome, virtualbox, gui

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 i686 in VirtualBox. I get this giant gap on my top toolbar and it's driving me nuts. Any way I can fix it?

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Left of the up arrow there are 3 gray stripes under eachother.
Drag them to the right and the icons will follow.

[image]

Rightclick and choose 'lock to panel' first otherwise it does not move.

[image]

edit: you are probably just aiming left or right of the 3 stripes.It is a rather narrow margin. Your popup shows up when you rightclick on an empty space on the panel.

[image]

Comment: Can't grab the grippy thing. Won't move :(

Comment: And he needs to uncheck "lock" , if they are locked. Then to move them.

Comment: @binarylife +1 @Mark he's correct! edited it in :)

Comment: @binarylife: I don't have that option. See update.

Comment: @Mark you moved the connection icon to the right of the mail icon. So it does work!? Or ...

Comment: @Mark , You have 3 Icons right? these are called systray, or notification icons. You should do a right click below the message icon or between the message icon and sound menu. ( not over the separator)  and you should see like the picture that my friend Rinzwind posted above.

Comment: @Rinzwind: Nah, I think that was from rebooting. @binarylife: Right clicking just beneath the mail icon did it...had to right click again and click move to move the sound and mail icon, but the Wired Network icon I still can't seem to move.

Comment: The wired network has to be the 3 stripes and you need to rightlick it to get my 2nd image. It -has- to. Really.

Comment: @Rinzwind: Double right clicking the grip finally made the menu pop up... not sure why it was so finicky.

Comment: @mark glad it worked!!! @binarylife I was making exact the same image :D when I relogged back to Unity you beat me to it :D

Comment: @Rinzwind: Thanks :) Your popup looks more messed up than mine with those gradients and the spacing between items.

Comment: @Rinzwind: Hehe Oops :D, I was a little bit faster:D ,anyway I missed this panel !